# Check what kind of hardware slots are available linux

Tags: linux, operating-systems

My laptop comes in different models, some of them have an m.2 sdd slot. The retailer I bought it from doesn't provide information in great detail and I'd like to know without opening up the laptop if I have m.2 available.

Is there a command I can run to check that? Like lspci for example?

Comment: Have you looked at the output of "dmidecode" ?

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't fint anywhere saying "m.2" with grep.. Is it possible it's listed by some other identifier?

Comment: Dont know. Don't have any m.2 devices. What is the make and model of your laptop?